# jQuery add two CSS property values

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I was trying to get the top position of the element and the margin-bottom value.
that worked:

```
var top = -$('elem').postion().top; // lets say its -54
var margin = $('elem').css('margin-top'); // lets say its 0
```

Bud I need to add these up for my animate function. so `top+margin` but jQuery gives -540 px but it need to return -54 px.. or when its negative it just gives -54-10px when I need -64 px.

Is there someting to get this fixed? I can't come up with it and it annoys me!

My code:

```
var top = -$('#id1').position().top;
var margin = $('.scrollable').css('margin-top');

var combine = top+margin;

$('.animate').animate({'margin-top' : combine});
```

Comment: the second one is a string (eg: "10px")...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Bud i need to add these up for my animate function. so top+margin but jQuery gives 540 p

`css` values are strings, so since one of your operands is a string, the `+` is being interpreted as a concatenation operator (`54 + "0" = "540"`), not an addition operator. [(Details)](http://es5.github.com/#x11.6.1) To turn them into numbers, use [`parseInt(str, 10)`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.2.2), e.g.:

```
// I believe `top` will already be a number; check and if not, use parseInt here too,
// e.g. var top = -parseInt($('#id1').position().top, 10);
var top = -$('#id1').position().top;

// This will definitely be a string that needs parsing; note that we're assuming
// here that the margin has been given in `px` units.
var margin = parseInt($('.scrollable').css('margin-top'), 10);

// Now this + is an addition, not a concatenation    
var combine = top+margin;

$('.animate').animate({'margin-top' : -combine});
```

Comment: @Misiur isn't it the default conversion anyways?

Comment: Or use `+str` to convert to a number

Comment: Default is auto. Depends on what the string contains. So it will not be always 10. Can cause some nice bugs :).

Comment: @Xeon06: The default is "it depends on the string." Hence, always use it if you know the radix of the input.

Comment: Ah, actually, it *should* only parse as base 8 if the first character is '0'. [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). However, as the page mentions it, it is better to always put it, since it's implementation can vary. Thanks for the tip guys.

Comment: @Xeon06: its not a real problem, `parseInt` trys to be cool and figure out the base value for your if not passed. So especially for numbers that start with a zero, this leads to trouble if you don't pass a radix.

Answer (score 3):

It's because it returns the values as strings, and using the `+` operator on them concatenates. You can use `parseInt` to get a number from a string. It'll even work if there is a `px` suffix, though it will stop at that.

```
var top = $('elem').postion().top;
var margin = $('elem').css('margin-top');

var total = parseInt(top, 10) + parseInt(margin, 10);
```

Comment: Important use `parseFloat` or `parseInt(int, 10);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var combine = parseInt(top) + parseInt(margin);
```